# MariaDB view vs simple query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the two tables defined as follows:

```
User(id, name, email, password ...)
  PK(id)

Friends(friend_one, friend_two, since ...)
  FK(friend_one) REFERENCES User(id)
  FK(friend_two) REFERENCES User(id)
```

In my system I want to do queries that involve both tables like (this is not the unike query I want to do that involves joins over both tables):
"Get all friends of a given user (including there names ...)"

In this case, what's your opinion about using a view with the following structure?
VW(userid, friend_name, friend_email ...)

Or should I just use a simple query?

Thanks

Comment: Also when I'm talking about using a view, I'm thinking about a materialized view

Comment: In any other database, I would say "use a view".  For MySQL and MariaDB, I'd say "test it and see if you get any performance."

Comment: @GordonLinoff The thing is, mariaDB and mysql don't support indexed views (only support materialized views using flexview), and since in my sample query I won't select all the rows that are present in the view, the usage of a view may be a performance killer. On the other hand if I use a simples query, I can select all the id's of users that are friends with a specific user, and then join this id's with the correspondent data. This is the reason that make me think that I shouldn't use a view in this case.

Comment: Materialized views do not exist in mysql.  While you cannot index views since they are not materialized in mysql, the view itself will use the underline indexes from the tables it is constructed from. I use views in mysql like sub-queries or to force a query plan.